# Problems performing WebSocket handshake with Apache Vysper

Tags: javascript, apache, websocket, handshake

I’m having an issue performing a successful handshake. Weather running Vysper standalone or embedded in a simple Java Server (of my own making, or one of the prepackaged examples), I get the same error condition upon attempting to connect from a JavaScript client (my own or one of the prepackaged examples). The error that returns is a HTTP 405 Response, reported in Chrome's console as “Unexpected response code: 405”.

**Configuration of Standalone Server:**

‘spring-config.xml’ has the following additions:

```
    <bean id="websocketEndpoint" class="org.apache.vysper.xmpp.extension.websockets.WebSocketEndpoint"> 
        <property name="port" value="8080" /> 
        <property name="contextPath" value="/ws" /> 
    </bean>
```

And in the server constructor:

```
   <ref bean="websocketEndpoint"/>
```

**Possible Error Condition upon Server Start:**

The Server appears to start properly, only with the following possible problem reported (on both standalone and embedded servers):

```
  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@2af081 STOPPED 
   +-SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 
   +-qtp29384701{8<=6<=8/254,0} 
   +-ServletContextHandler@32efa7@32efa7/ws,null started 
      +-{} 
      +-{} 
     +-SessionHandler@1fbfd6 started 
        +-ServletHandler@6b9c84 started 
           +-[/ws]=>org.apache.vysper.xmpp.extension.websockets.XmppWebSocketServlet-23860799{}
```

**Error Upon Attempting Connection:**

When attempting to connect from the client the following is logged in both types of server instance:

```
  17:04:02,137 | DEBUG | org.eclipse.jetty.util.log | REQUEST /ws/ws on org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$3@c3615b 
  17:04:02,137 | DEBUG | org.eclipse.jetty.util.log | sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@1767f84 
  17:04:02,137 | DEBUG | org.eclipse.jetty.util.log | session=null 
  17:04:02,137 | DEBUG | org.eclipse.jetty.util.log | servlet=org.apache.vysper.xmpp.extension.websockets.XmppWebSocketServlet-29347786 
  17:04:02,137 | DEBUG | org.eclipse.jetty.util.log | servlet holder= 
  17:04:02,137 | DEBUG | org.eclipse.jetty.util.log | chain= 
  17:04:02,137 | DEBUG | org.eclipse.jetty.util.log | RESPONSE /ws/ws 405 
  17:04:02,137 | DEBUG | org.eclipse.jetty.util.log | EOF
```

And in the Chrome console on the client side:

```
  Unexpected response code: 405 
  Event {clipboardData: undefined, cancelBubble: false, returnValue: true, srcElement: WebSocket, defaultPrevented: false…} 
  CloseEvent {reason: "", code: 1006, wasClean: false, clipboardData: undefined, cancelBubble: false…}
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?